# Mediawiki dropdown value: from category + none

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

In mediawiki, I made a form with some dropdown lists that get their values from a category:

```
{{{field|Managers|mandatory|input type=dropdown|values from category=myTeam}}}
```

This works, it will show me a list of everyone in my team. However, somehow it should be possible to select "none", which is not in my category (duh!). Can someone tell me how to I can add an extra value to this dropdown list?

Comment: What extension(s) are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Create a page named `None` and populate it with `[[Category:myTeam]]` seems the simplest solution based on your details.